# Vue Typescript Define props with default values for complex objects

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typeerror

I am trying to strong type and give default values for an object prop in a component. The prop is called Entry. Entry structure is

```
interface Entry {
  id: number;
  body: string;
  emoji: Emjoi | null;
  createdAt: Date;
  userId: number;
}
```

This is using SFC (Single file component), Composition API and `<script setup>`

But I can't seem to get default values for the prop using withDefaults

I looked through the Vue.js docs for typescript you can uses withDefaults
https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props
and for arrays you do this:

```js
export interface Props {
  msg?: string
  labels?: string[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: 'hello',
  labels: () => ['one', 'two']
})
```

But I tried to do the same for an object and got errors

```js
interface Props {
  entry: Entry;
  userName: string;
}

const entryDefault: Entry = {
  id: 1,
  body: "",
  emoji: null,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  userId: 1,
};

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  entry: () => 
    {
      id: 1,
      body: "",
      emoji: null,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      userId: 1,
    },
```

Comment: can you share the error that you're getting?

Comment: You need to put parenthesis around the object in the arrow function, i.e. `entry: () => ({id: 1, ...})` or use the full `entry: () => {return {id: 1, ...}}`, otherwise JS thinks the braces declare the function body instead of an object, and  you get a syntax error. Is that the problem you are having?

Comment: Thank you this code now works
```
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  entry: () => {
    return {
      id: 1,
      body: "",
      emoji: null,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      userId: 1,
    };
  },
  userName: "Unknown",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was not adding a return for entry. The correct code looks like this:

```
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  entry: () => {
    return {
      id: 1,
      body: "",
      emoji: null,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      userId: 1,
    };
  },
  userName: "Unknown",
});
```

Thank you
Moritz Ringler
for the help